# Consume wadl service in php

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, wadl

I need  to call a method from a wadl service and pass a parameter

```
wadl: http://domain.com/application.wadl 
method: checkInfo
```

How can i do that?

```
//Wsdl - Soap: I need to do this but with a wadl service

$wsdl = new SoapClient('http://domain.com/application?wsdl');

$wsdl->__call('checkInfo',array('data'=> ''));
//or
$wsdl->checkInfo(array('data'=> ''));
```

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using SOAP server :

```
class MyClass{
    function checkInfo() {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
//when in non-wsdl mode the uri option must be specified
$options=array('uri'=>'http://localhost/');
//create a new SOAP server
$server = new SoapServer(NULL,$options);
//attach the API class to the SOAP Server
$server->setClass('MyClass');
//start the SOAP requests handler
$server->handle();
```

then use it :

```
<?php
 /*
 * PHP SOAP - How to create a SOAP Server and a SOAP Client
 */

$options = array('location' => 'http://localhost/server.php', 
                  'uri' => 'http://localhost/');
//create an instante of the SOAPClient (the API will be available)
$api = new SoapClient(NULL, $options);
//call an API method
echo $api->checkInfo();
 ?>
```

code example from [here](http://code.runnable.com/UmqriSbs5EI9AADN/how-to-create-a-soap-server-and-a-soap-client-for-soapserver-soapclient-and-php)